# lim sup of i.i.d. random variables in terms of their distribution function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Let $(X_n)$ be i.i.d. with distribution function $F$.

I'm asked to prove that $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n = M \text{ almost surely}$$

where $M = \inf\{t \in \mathbb R : F(t) = 1\}$.

My approach has been to formulate the lim sup in terms of events that occur infinitely often or not, and then to try apply the Borel-Cantelli lemmas, but I couldn't see this to the end. I also wonder if Kolmogorov 0-1 law could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution. Let i.o. denote "infinitely often" and BC1,2 be the two Borel-Cantelli lemmas.

$$\begin{aligned}P(\limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n = K) = 1 &\iff P(X_n > aK \text{ i.o}) = 0 \text{ and } P(X_n > bK \text{ i.o.})
= 1 \ \forall a, b \in \mathbb Q, a > 1, b < 1\\
&\stackrel{BC1,2}{\impliedby} \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X_n > cK )  \begin{cases}<\infty & c > 1\\ = \infty & c < 1\end{cases}\\
&\iff \sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-F(cK))  \begin{cases}<\infty & c > 1\\ = \infty & c < 1\end{cases}\\
&\iff F(cK) \begin{cases}=1& c > 1\\ <1 & c < 1\end{cases}\\
&\iff K = \inf\{t: F(t) = 1\}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: I think the idea is one of the right ones, but:
$F(cK) = 0$ for $c<1$ is wrong.
Furthermore you have to be careful with the term above saying for ALL $a> 1, b< 1$ because this is not a countable condition (you could add $a,b \in \Bbb Q$).

Comment: fixed, i think.